# Cell merging or Row span dynamiclly in Jasper iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to design the following format in iReport, but not getting as expected. I am going to show only one Customer Group which has multiple Customers.

Worth mentioning, I will be using this report as a subreport in another report(main_report). From main_report I am passing 3 parameters to the subreport. The subreport will be placed in Title band in the main_report as I want to show it once.

**What I want:**

[image: expected output image]

**What I got**:

[image: current output image]

**My XML code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="main_report_subreport" language="groovy" pageWidth="380" pageHeight="572" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="380" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="b21df19b-8b19-4120-9689-f0eb8e8a2836">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.6105100000000032"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="GROUPCODE" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT G.CLGROUPS_NAME, C.CLIENTS_NAME
  FROM CLGROUPS G
  JOIN GRPCLIENTSDTL P
  ON ( G.CLGROUPS_CODE = P.GRPCLDTL_GROUP_CODE)
  JOIN CLIENTS C
  ON (P.GRPCLDTL_CLIENT_CODE = C.CLIENTS_CODE)
WHERE P.GRPCLDTL_ENTITY_NUM = 1
   AND P.GRPCLDTL_GROUP_CODE = $P{GROUPCODE}
ORDER BY P.GRPCLDTL_SL]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CLGROUPS_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CLIENTS_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="177" height="20" uuid="b36c2b01-927b-4d2c-b20d-eb83d37b9a54"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer Group Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="177" y="0" width="203" height="20" uuid="2c7934f3-aa48-4e03-a5c9-c010b8f00235"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="177" height="20" uuid="fccb7027-7f1f-47b3-9d7e-f2c72683283d"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CLGROUPS_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="177" y="0" width="203" height="20" uuid="dc5bda3e-7221-4751-86a0-f12c06f4c089"/>
                <box leftPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CLIENTS_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I googled and tried several ways, but neither found the feasible solution nor the expected output.